# How to create a ColorDrawable from Jetpack Compose Color?

Tags: colors, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to convert jetpack Compose's `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` to `android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable` ?

I tried `ColorDrawable(Color.Red.toArgb())` but its not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried it in the correct way.

Here is a sample that does work

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Red

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(20.dp),
        factory = { context ->
            View(context).apply {
                background = ColorDrawable(color.toArgb())  
            }
        }
    )    
}
```

Comment: Well, I was trying it with AsyncImage, and it was not working. I ended up using ColorPainter instead.